# What is the relation between Viraj, Hiranyagarbha, Brahma, and Saguna Brahman in Advaita terminology?

Tags: philosophy, brahma, vedanta, brahman, advaita

In [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe15/sbe15075.htm) of the Brihadaranyaka Upanishad, the sage Yagnavalkya tells his disciple king Janaka about the levels of bliss among beings in different Lokas:

> Now a hundred of these human blessings make one blessing of the fathers who have conquered the world (of the fathers). A hundred blessings of the fathers who have conquered this world make one blessing in the Gandharva world. A hundred blessings in the Gandharva world make one blessing of the Devas by merit (work, sacrifice), who obtain their godhead by merit. A hundred blessings of the Devas by merit make one blessing of the Devas by birth, also (of) a Srotriya who is without sin, and not overcome by desire. A hundred blessings of the Devas by birth make one blessing in the world of Pragâpati, also (of) a Srotriya who is without sin, and not overcome. by desire. A hundred blessings in the world of Pragâpati make one blessing in the world of Brahman, also (of) a Srotriya who is without sin, and not overcome by desire. And this is the highest blessing.

[Here](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc120049.html) is what the Advaitin Acharya Adi Shankarachrya says about this verse:

> This human joy multiplied a hundred times makes one unit of joy for the Manes. They are qualified by the clause ‘who have won that world of theirs,’ i.e. who have pleased the Manes by the performance of obsequial rites etc., and have won their way to their world. Their measure of joy is the human joy multiplied a hundred times. That again multiplied a hundred times makes one unit of joy in the world of the celestial minstrels. That again multiplied a hundred times makes one unit of joy for the gods by action—those who attain their godhead by their actions such as the Agnihotra enjoined by the Śrutis. Similarly one unit of joy for the gods by birth, those who are gods from their very birth, as well as of one who is versed in the Vedas, sinless, i.e. doing what is prescribed by the scriptures, and free from desire for all objects below the level of the gods by birth. That his joy equals theirs is gathered from the word ‘ca’ (and) in the text. **That multiplied a hundred times makes one unit of joy in the world of Prajāpati, i.e. in the body of Virāj, as well as of one who is versed in the Vedas, sinless and free from desire—this has already been explained—and who meditates on him. That multiplied a hundred times makes one unit of joy in the world of Brahman, i.e. in the body of Hiraṇyagarbha, as well as of one who, etc.—already explained. After this mathematical calculations cease.**

This is as good an opportunity as any to clarify some pieces of Advaita terminology I'm somewhat confused about.  My question is, who are Viraj and Hiranyagarbha in Advaita terminology?

By default one might assume that Hiranyagarbha refers to the god Brahma, husband of Saraswati, because Brahma was born from a golden seed or Hiranya Garbha.  But I get the sense that this is not how Advaitins use these terms.  Here is how I think they use these terms:

> Viraj = Karya Brahman = Brahma husband of Saraswati
>
> Hiranyagarbha = Karana Brahman = Saguna Brahman

Karana Brahman refers to Saguna Brahman being the eternal reflection of Nirguna Brahman in the world of Avidya (according to Advaita), and being the cause of the material world.  Karya Brahman refers to the fact that Brahma is a created being.

In any case, is my understanding of Advaita terminology correct?  One thing that militates against my understanding is [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saguna_brahman#Yoga):

> Hiranyagarbha, the collection of deities in the Hindu pantheon of gods, is not saguna brahman as popularly misconstrued. Sankara clearly says that hiranyagarbha is called brahman only because of nearness to brahman. After many millions of years, the devotees who reach the worlds of gods (hiranyagarbha), will reach the state of vishnu. This is called advaita siddhi and this state can be reached here and now by one who is free from all desires and blessed by the lord.

Wikipedia seems to be saying that Hiranyagarbha just refers to Saraswati's husband Brahma in Advaita terminology, but I think that's wrong.  I think that's just a confusion due to the fact that as I said above Brahma is often called Hiranyagarbha due to the that he was born from an egg.

Are there any Advaita works that clarify this terminology?  By the way, I should mention that at least according to the Sri Vaishnava sect (of which I am a member), Saguna Brahman is considered supreme and he's equated with Para Vasudeva or the highest Vishnu.

Comment: Being a part time (or convenience based) *Advaitan*, *saguna Brahman = VAsudeva* & *nirguna Brahman = Atma* is something I have understood so far. Have also seen *Vishnu* & *Shiva* being used respectively, with people adding *mahA* or *sadA* prefixes before it to make it more fine grained. In general *Brahman* & *Brahma (BrahM)* are same. Probably you meant *BrahmA* (or Brahmā). Now *saguna Brahman* (or *VAsudeva* or Vishnu) is not cause or creator of universe, but the universe itself. Not sure if Gita is qualified for *Advaita*, as there is no formal word in it. Hence putting as a comment.

Comment: @iammilind The purpose of my question is not about understanding Nirguna Brahman and Saguna Brahman; I know what those mean.  I'm interested in what Viraj and Hiranyagarbha mean in Advaitic terminology.

Comment: @iammilind By the way, since you brought it up, Advaitins believe that Ishwara, aka Saguna Brahman, is the creator of the Universe, in fact he is both the efficient cause and the material cause of the Universe (meaning Saguna Brahman is both the substance that the Universe is made of and the one who directs its creation, preservation, and destruction). At least that's what they believe from the relative perspective. in reality they believe that the Universe does not exist, only Nirguna Brahman exists. (Again, I suggest you read Adi Shankaracharya's commentary on the Mandukya Upabishad.)

Comment: @iammilind And if you're asking if the Bhagavad Gita follows Advaita, as a Sri Vaishnava I would tell you no, it follows Visistadvaita :-)

Comment: Check this [site](http://hinduwebsite.com/brahmanaspects.asp) and this [quora question](https://www.quora.com/Is-Purana-Brahmaji-same-as-Vedic-Hiranyagarva). In the image you wil see, Ishwara or Saguna Brahman is in Nirgun Brahman as per Advaita, but if reversed, it can also be infered as Brahman being part of Ishwara. Further, Hiranyagarbha is Brahmaji who arose from naval of Lord Vishnu/Ishwar and means Subtle body or their collection, while Viraj is gross body or matter. In elemental form, Ishwara is Akasha and Hiranayagarbha is Prana and their combination leads to gross manifestation.

Comment: As per Shaivism, Shiva is Ishwara and Shakti is Hiranayagarbha/Prana while in Christianity they are known as Holy Father and Holy Spirit. Basically soul and mind.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, with my last Q hopefully we will have some answer, if Advaita thinks of universe as "unreal" or "unworthy". *MithyA* certainly doesn't mean unreal (non existent). Probably you may post an answer if you have read Upanishada already. :-) Regarding Gita, all *X-Dvaita-s* points to Gita itself. They are just various interpretations only. Saying Gita follows only *Vishishtadvaita* is an understatement. Advaita is also another interpretation of Gita. Same thing for other *AchAryas*' interpretations.

Comment: I think Viraj refers to the Giant Purusha avatara of Vishnu right after Lord Brahma was born. (The Sahasrashirsha Purusha)

Comment: @Surya Well, that would be kind of confusing, since the Purusha Sukta says that from the (Sahasrashirsha) Purusha, Viraj was born, and from  Viraj, Purusha was born.  I assumed that Viraj in that verse referred to Brahma.  After all, Brahma came out of the navel of a Sahasrashirsha form of Vishnu known as Aniruddha, one of the four Vyuhas.

Comment: @Keshav In the Devi Bhagavatam (which obviously you don't accept) Vishnu who appears from Krsna is called Viraj who in turn produces Purusha for the sake of creation.

Comment: @Surya Yeah, I especially don't accept it if it says Vishnu comes from Krishna.  In any case, I don't think that is how Adi Shankaracharya is using the term Viraj.  He is connecting Viraj to the Loka of Prajapati, and then he is connecting Hiranyagarbha to a higher Loka than that.  So that would suggest that Viraj is Brahma in this context.

Comment: @Surya At least in Vaishnava terms, I think when Adi Shankaracharya is talking about the body of Viraj, he's referring to the fact that the inhabitants of Satyaloka gradually merge into the body of Brahma before they attain Moksa, and then when he talks about the body of Hiranyagarbha he's talking about Jivas who unite with the body of Sriman Narayana (specifically Para Vasudeva) in Vaikuntha.

Comment: @iammilind I agree that people have many interpretations of the Bhagavad Gita, but I think most of those interpretations are wrong.  I think there is such a thing as an objectively correct interpretation of the Bhagavad Gita, and as a Sri Vaishnava I think that interpretation is Visistadvaita.

Comment: @iammilind Regarding your question about the world being unreal, I generally don't answer Advaita questions, because they're usually answered by so many other users, since this site has lots of Advaitin users like Swami Vishwananda, Sai, etc. (The only reason I posted an answer on your question about the soul being eternal is that it's something that all the Vedantic philosophies agree on, not just Advaita.) But yeah, I could post an answer, since no one else seems interested.

Comment: The problem with this sort of question is - it depends. It's not so much an advaita standpoint it's what different srutis say. In different Upanishads some of the names are used interchangeably, in some others there are used to denote Saguna Brahman in different aspects, in others some of the names are spoken of being of the Saguna aspect but one of the other names denotes the first created being. Its for this reason that the commentators are important and for having a teacher help you understand how to interpret.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda OK, but can you at least try to explain to me how these terms are being used in the Adi Shankaracharya quote in my question?  In that quote, which name corresponds to Saguna Brahman, which name corresponds to Brahma, and what are the specific Lokas being described?

Answer (score 2):

There is a discussion of Isvara, Hiranyagarbha and Virat in the Chapter 'The Lamp of the Picture' of the Advaita text Pancadasi of Sri Vidyaranya Swami.

> The Sruti, in the passage beginning with 'the consciousness in the
>   deep sleep' and ending in 'He is the Lord of all' describes this
>    **'sheath of bliss' as the Isvara**.

Pancadasi translated by Swami Swahananda, VI.158

> As the deep sleep state passes into dream state, so Isvara who is
>   known as the sheath of bliss, transforms Himself into Hiranyagarbha,
>   when He, the one, wills to be many.

Pancadasi VI.198

> Hiranyagarbha or Sutratman, otherwise called the subtle-body, is the
>   **totality of the subtle bodies of all Jivas**. He conceives Himself as
>   the totality of all egoes or 'I'- consciousnesses, like the threads of
>   a piece of cloth; and He is said to be endowed with powers of
>   volition, conation and cognition.

Pancadasi VI.200

> Like a tender offshoot of a germinated corn or like a tender plant
>   sprouting, Hiranyagarbha is the tender bud of the world which is still
>   indistinct.

Pancadasi VI.203

> In Virat the world appears distinct and shining,like objects in broad
>   day-light or like the figures of a fully painted picture or the fruit
>   of a fully matured tree. **In Virat all the gross bodies are plainly
>   seen**.

Pancadasi VI.204

> In the Visvarupa chapter and in the Purusa Sukta there is a
>   description of Virat. **From the creator Brahma to a blade of grass,
>   all the objects in the world form part of Virat**.

Pancadasi VI.205

Swami Swahananda writes:

> Here Isvara is the consciousness reflected in the totality of
>   bliss-sheaths. ... Each individual soul, Jiva, has three states of
>   consciousness; the waking (when the Jiva is called the Visva). the
>   dreaming (when he is called Taijasa) and the deep sleep (when he is
>   known as Prajna). Isvara, the collective consciousness,  has also
>   three corresponding states - the Vaisvanara, the Hiranyagarbha, and
>   the Isvara. ... Just as the three states of a Jiva do not make him
>   three, even so the three states of Isvara do not make him a triple
>   personality. Just as Prajna, being the causal state of a Jiva,
>   includes the other two sates of his and is the guide and controller of
>   them; so the third state of Isvara, being the causal one, is the
>   source, the indwelling Spirit, controller and guide of the other two
>   and through them of the entire universe.

Pancadasi translated by Swami Swahananda

Now that we know wha Virat, Hiranyagarbha and Isvara mean in Advaita Vedanta, how are these three related to Brahma and Saguna Brahman? The creator Brahma is part of Virat according to Pancadasi VI.205.

> Sruti says that this(pure universal) consciousness reflected in Maya
>   is Isvara which controls Maya as well. The great Isvara is the inner
>   ruler, ominiscient, and the cause of the universe.

Pancadasi VI.157

Isvara who is Cit reflected on Maya, is not the same as (Nirguna) Brahman, who is Cit, the attributeless existence. Isvara is what is called Saguna Brahman or Brahman with attributes in Advaita Vedanta.

Shankara of course considers Isvara or Brahman with attributes as ultimately unreal. He writes in his commentary on Brahma Sutra Bhasya III.II.18:

> Since this Self is by nature Consciousness Itself, distinctionless,
>   beyond speech and mind, and can be taught by way of negating other
>   things, hence in the scriptures dealing with liberation an
>   illustration is cited by saying that it is "like the sun reflected in
>   water". Here the aspect kept in view is the one with attributes, which
>   is not real and which is created by limiting adjuncts, as it is done
>   in such texts, "As this luminous sun, though one in itself, becomes
>   multifarious owing to its entry into water divided by different pots,
>   similarly this Deity, the birthless, self-effulgent Self, though one,
>   seems to be diversified owing to its entry into the different bodies,
>   constituting its limiting adjuncts." Similarly, 'Being but one, the
>   Universal Soul is present in all beings, though One, It is seen as
>   many, like the moon in water" (Amritabindu, 12) and other texts.

Brahma Sutra Bhasya of Sri Sankaracharya, III.II.18

Comment: But what is the relation between Viraj, Hiranyagarbha, and Ishwara to Brahma and Saguna Brahman?  Adi Shankaracharya connects these beings to very specific Lokas one can attain in the afterlife.

Comment: Pancadasi VI.205 clearly says that the creator Brahma is part of Virat.

Comment: OK, but Adi Shankaracharya says that one hundred times the joy of the gods "makes one unit of joy in the world of Prajāpati, i.e. in the body of Virāj," He seems to think being in the body of Viraj is far, far more enjoyable than life on Earth.  In any case, what does Saguna Brahman correspond to here?  Also, what is the Loka that "the body of Hiranyagarbha" corresponds to?

Comment: Virat is the sum total of all gross bodies which includes the creator Brahma, Visnu, SIva etc (Pancadasi VI.206). Of course body of Virat will be more enjoyable than life on earth since that body contains the body of Brahma, Siva, Visnu and others.. Virat is the gross body of Saguna Brahman or Isvara. Hiranyagarbha is the subtle body of Isvara or Isvara's 'I' consciousness. I am not sure about the Loka that corresponds to the subtle body of Isvara.

Comment: Well, but if Virat consists of all gross bodies, then aren't we already part of Virat?  So then why does Adi Shankaracharya connect being in the body of Virat to "the world of Prajapati", i.e. Brahma?  Is it that only someone dwelling in the world of Brahma can see all of Virat?  And yeah, hopefully I can find out the Loka that corresponds to Hiranyagarbha, the Loka that the Brihadaranyaka Upanishads calls "the world of Brahman."  At least in the Sri Vaishnava view that would correspond to Vishnu's abode of Paramapadam, given that it's above the world of Brahma and the other material Lokas.

Comment: We are part of Virat. In fact Pancadasi VI.205 says that all of this universe created by Brahma is part of Virat.

Comment: Then what did you mean by "Of course body of Virat will be more enjoyable than life on earth"? How can that be if life on Earth already involves being in the body of Virat?

Comment: We are not spiritually advanced to see Virat. Just think of Gita Chapter 11.

Comment: So yeah, so it's like I suggested above: "So then why does Adi Shankaracharya connect being in the body of Virat to "the world of Prajapati", i.e. Brahma? Is it that only someone dwelling in the world of Brahma can see all of Virat?"  In any case, I'm still hoping that someone will be able to answer what Loka corresponds to the body of Hiranyagarbha, the Loka that Adi Shankaracharya calls 'the world of Brahman".

Comment: In Advaita, Brahma loka is what is generally understood as Satya loka, the ultimate in created world. Advaita does not accept a physical world beyond Satya loka. In the Narayaneeyam 90th dashakam, this Satya loka is stated as the loka of Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva. http://www.mediafire.com/…/Hari_Hara_abheda..Narayanee…/file     In Advaita, Saguna Brahma loka is the abode of Brahma. The advaitic concept is: if a person is a devotee of any of the Trimurtis, he finally goes to this Brahma loka (there is no kailasa, vaikuntha terminology in Advaita) and gets Brahma jnanam there and freed forever.

Comment: @vsubrahmanian Thanks for the info on Brahma loka as per Advaita. Do Advaitins say anything in their texts, which trimurti is the presiding deity in Advaita's Brahma Loka?

Comment: The Crimson Universe:  As stated earlier, Advaita holds Brahma, the four-faced, as the presiding Lord of Brahma Loka. He will help the residents of Brahma loka to attain the Enlightening knowledge. When the entire creation goes into dissolution, pralaya, mode, this Satya/Brahma loka too will perish and all the residents there who have had the enlightening knowledge, along with Brahma, will attain non-returnable Mukti.