# What are the some books that relate Hinduism to science?

Tags: science

I was reading a book by Dalai Lama called "The universe in a single atom"   which relates Buddhism to science.

Similarly, it would be great to know of some books that relate Hinduism to science.

Some books, which can give me some cognitive and theoretical understanding of the religion of Hinduism.

By the way, religion is not just a religion to me, it is much more than that.

Comment: "The Lost Discoveries -The Ancient roots of Modern Science" is a book by Dick Teresi.It has something on the  relation between Hinduism and science

Comment: [Hindu Cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_cosmology) may be interested for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"What is Life? with 'Mind and Matter'" by Erwin Schrodinger - winner of the Nobel Prize for his discovery of the dual nature of light, he mentions Vedanta specifically in this book

"Quantum Physics and Ultimate Reality: Mystical Writings of Great Physicists" Michael Green, editor - many philosophical musings of Einstein, Schrodinger, Pauli, Planck, Bohr, Heisenberg, etc., etc. with their own thoughts and arguments as to how hard sciences fail in the end and lead to the 'One'.

"Spooky Action at a Distance: The Phenomenon That Reimagines Space and Time" by George Musser - published only last year, the author has no exposure to Vedanta, but when you read the book, you will the similarities of Vedanta as to where current theories are going.

Also, Patanjali's "Yoga Aphorisms". he speaks of the evolution of species thousands of years before the Darwin.

Comment: Can you take a look at my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11158/36 It's about Advaita terminology.